# How can I send a command to all connected clients from a putty terminal window?

Tags: linux, sockets, pthreads

I have 4 robots which have a linux OS and are currently communicating between each other using the client-server model. The server (leader robot) creates a thread for each client that connects to it.

I however need a 'kill switch' to stop the robots all at once. I have a function that will stop the robots however I need a method by which I send this command (or a message of some sort) to all the connected clients at the same time.

Comment: Is your requirement really so stringent that sending four seperate messages it not good enough? You are never going to acheive *exactly* the same time as there are always latencies throughout any system.

Comment: Does sending 4 messages in a few millinseconds, still counts as "all at once?As Colin says, send it in 4 steps, first the 3 clients, then the server.

Comment: @kaylum No they do not have be at exactly the same time since they are robots moving at very slow speeds. My problem is that if one robot decides to go out of control I have to literally run after it and catch it. I would like to send a simple command of some sort to stop everything at one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Human reaction time is going to be about 250ms by the time you see something wrong and then press 'enter' to stop. You could send one message to the leader and have it shutdown each of its clients, then shutdown itself.

For a 'kill switch', I'd suggest the leader send 'keep alive' messages to the clients. The clients would then shutdown automatically (watchdog timer), even if all communication is lost.

If it was really critical, you could have the leader also need constant data from the putty terminal (hold down a key). Once the data stops (release the key) it will stop, and its clients would also stop.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your best bet is to just send them one at a time.

I'm guessing you're using TCP sockets to communicate between them. There's no way to "instantly" send out commands at the same time using TCP.

Of course there is a way... you could have all the robots listening on a multicast address, and then have the leader send a kill message via multicast. the only issue with this is it will be over UDP. so the slave robots are not guaranteed to receive it, like they are with TCP.